# Install MySql from config file

Tags: mysql

I just want to know is there any configuration file MySql has, just like configuration.ini of SqlServer, which I can use to install & configure MySql silently from an application.

Comment: what the platform? windows, unix, mac os x? did you hear anything about embedden mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called `my.cnf` under Unix, and `my.ini` under Windows. If you are on a Linux environment it's most probably under `/etc/my.cnf`.